# Orca doesn't speak in Java Swing application

Tags: gnome, java, accessibility, orca

How to make the Orca screen reader read Java Swing Application on java 18 and higher. As far as I understand, I need `java-atk-wrapper`. After installing it, I launch the application with the command `java -jar -Dassistive_technologies=org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper -verbose:jni test.jar`.

In the logs I see movement through application elements, but Orca is silent. Tell me how to properly launch a Java Swing application so that Orca can speak it.

Ubunthu OS 20.04
Orca 3.36.2